# How to structure Cordova project using Onsen + Angular in Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, onsen-ui

Can anyone help me to structure my brand new cordova app using vs15 and Onsen with Angular. I need to know the folder structure as well as in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many approaches. If you want to target for your app you have to think and structure. Since you want to know the folder structure i will provide some guidelines to follow
Lets say you are going to develop a Taxi application.
This have two main actors **Driver** and **Customer**

> 1) Breakdown common factors under www

css,
images,
lib,
scripts,
views

> 2) Dive into each folder

Css > Common *(login page, slide menu css)* 
Images > Common *(logo)*, Driver, Customer 
Lib > Folder for each 3rd party thing *(jquery, chartjs)* 
Scripts > Common *(login)*, Driver, Customer 
Views > Common *(login)*, Driver, Customer. But dont put index.html into any folder.

> 3) Common Usage and useful things

If you find anything in common create Enum factory and put them into that.Then call that enum in such controller.

Always use setMain Page to clear the stack

If you want to come back from a page use poppage dont again push the page. If you push it will added to same stack. It will leads to some other issue. Poppage will remove that page from the page stack.

Always use angular stuffs rather than JQuery.

Create a common ons-model in index.html to use whenever your want to disable user interaction with the application.

> 4) Common issues and workarounds
>   Link coder : plugin issue ( when added some plugins, iOS have dependencies with non added plugings, so we have to add them too....)

Cannot accuare connection : set both the pc and mac's network connection to a one  wifi

could not find developer disk image: xcode > project settings > Arachitectures > base sdk > set with mobile competible version.

could not find module xCode : go to mac find the the taco home and take the build file run it on xcode.

> 5) Precautions

Have a txt file with all your app information such as password and id you used to create android keystore. Take a copy of the keystore and back it up somewhere.

---

If anyone needs some help leave a comment.

Happy Coding.
-Charitha-

Comment: Thanks buddy. this is very helpfull =)